# TeeChart For Point having Value as 0

Tags: activex, teechart

I am plotting a Line Chart, The Problem is in my data some points have zero Value. If I do AddNull For that it don't show the X-axis Value for the same. Can anyone share a example of Using a AddNULL and Add in the same series Impact.

E.g I have a Series having 11 X- Pts, The Series Data is  (0,0,0,0,0,10,0,0,0,0,0)
The Point with value 10 should be shown at 5th place but in my case it is displayed at Position 0.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you use method SetNull or AddNullXY to make null, the values  you want and set the property TreatNull to DontPaint because the null values aren't visible. I have made a simple code for you, where I use method SetNull to add nulls in your series:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    TChart1.Aspect.View3D = False
    TChart1.AddSeries scLine
    TChart1.AddSeries scLine
    TChart1.Series(0).asLine.Pointer.Visible = True
    TChart1.Series(1).asLine.Pointer.Visible = True
    Dim i As Integer
     For i = 0 To 19
        TChart1.Series(0).AddXY i, Rnd, "", vbBlue
        If i = 5 Then
            TChart1.Series(1).AddXY i, 10, "", vbRed
        Else
            TChart1.Series(1).AddXY i,0, "", vbRed
        End If
    Next i

    For i = 0 To TChart1.Series(1).Count - 1
        If i <> 5 Then
            TChart1.Series(1).SetNull (i)
        End If
    Next i
    TChart1.Series(1).asLine.TreatNulls = tnDontPaint
End Sub
```

Could you tell us if previous works as you want?

Thanks,